# MS Exchange on-premise anti-spam switch

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, email-server, microsoft-office-365

Our SBS2011 on-premise anti-spam will be soon discontinued. The manufacturer suggested us:

> For an alternative solution, we recommends Exchange Online
>   Protection.

Can we use Exchange Online Protection with MS Exchange 2010 on premise? If not, is there any other -on premise- anti-spam tool we can purchase or shall we all migrate to Exchange Online at some point?

Comment: Mikael is right, I also find a similar case here for your reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3f04e0b3-99e5-485b-bfe6-193bb1c8a45a/guide-for-eop-for-exchange-2010-sp3?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaging  and this document: https://docs.microsoft.com/zh-cn/office365/SecurityCompliance/eop/best-practices-for-configuring-eop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOP can be used with on-premises Exchange solutions.
Technically what happens is that you point your MX records at EOP, and then set up an outbound connector from EOP to your on-prem server(s). You can also use EOP for outbound filtering by using them as a “smart host”.

The same principle applies to other cloud-based or on-prem anti-spam solutions.